# Ubuntu sdk filedialog

Tags: ubuntu, qml

```
I have tried to make a video playback with qml and the Ubuntu Linux SDK application and this is the code I have got so far:
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
Video {
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Please choose a file(.mp4)"



        Component.onCompleted: visible = true
    }
    id: video
    width : units.gu(120)
    height : units.gu(90)
    source : fileDialog.fileUrl
    MouseArea {
        Text
        {
            text : "click to play,space for stop,left and right to seek position in video"
        }
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            video.play()
        }
    }
    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: video.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video.pause() : video.play()
    Keys.onLeftPressed: video.seek(video.position - 5000)
    Keys.onRightPressed: video.seek(video.position + 5000)
}
```

The code runs perfectly fine from my IDE,however when I install it on my Ubuntu 15.04 with unity 8 on my laptop the app just crashes. I am guessing QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0 might not be part of the platform?Then how do I package it in my .click?Or is there an alternative that is part of the platform?

Comment: Probably, you have different version of Qt, installed in your OS and in IDE. Check it with `qmake -v`. `FileDialog` was introduced in Qt 5.1. Btw, what errors did you get?

Comment: Actually the thing is that the QML used in the Ubuntu sdk is a fork of the normal QML.So it actually is possible to import libraries from both the QML from the Ubuntu SDK and the normal SDK into the IDE.However when I install it on a live machine it does not work.I had a similar problem before and that is basically how a Ubuntu developer helped me,to replace libraries which originated from vanilla QML with the ones used in the SDK.But I can't find an equivalent dialog for picking files in the SDK.

Comment: Actually the thing is that the QML used in the Ubuntu sdk is a fork of the normal QML.So it actually is possible to import libraries from both the QML from the Ubuntu SDK and the normal SDK into the IDE.However when I install it on a live machine it does not work.I had a similar problem before and that is basically how a Ubuntu developer helped me,to replace libraries which originated from vanilla QML with the ones used in the SDK.But I can't find an equivalent dialog for picking files in the SDK.I did not get any errors,it just crashed.And there is no terminal emulator on it.